# Axes Rotation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, rotations

Given $$x^2 - 4xy + 5(\sqrt5y) + 4y^2 + 1 = 0$$
rotate the axes to eliminate the $xy$-term in the equation, then write the equation is standard form.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes). You will find many details on how to eliminate the xy term for conic sections.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your new coordinates are 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\
Y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi&\sin\phi\\
-\sin\phi&\cos\phi
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $c=\cos\phi,s=\sin\phi$. Your new equation is 
$$
(Xc-Ys)^2-4(Xc-Ys)(Xs+Yc)+5\sqrt5(Xs+Yc)+4(Xs+Yc)^2+1=0\\
$$
As there's no $XY$ term we have
$$
6sc=4(c^2-s^2)\implies \tan2\phi={4\over3}\implies \phi={1\over2}\arctan({4\over3})\\
\implies c={2\over\sqrt5},s={1\over\sqrt5}
$$
The new equation becomes
$$
Y^2+X+2Y+0.2=0
$$
So you have to rotate your axes by $\phi$ radian counter-clockwise.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got 6sc and 4(c^2-s^2)

Comment: Coefficient of $XY$ from the 1st term is $-2cs$, from the 2nd term is $4(c^2-s^2)$, from the penultimate term is $8sc$. Add them up and equate to $0$ and you get $6sc=4(c^2-s^2)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So to figure out the new equation, do I just substitute s and c back into the long equation then simplify?

Comment: Why did you divide the final equation by 5? Because I got 5Y^2+5X+10Y+1=0

Comment: Because I'm lazy and it's easier to write...

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't that change the graph of the parabola?

Answer (score 0):

$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
Then
$$\tan(2\theta)=\dfrac{B}{A–C}$$

For $x^2−4xy+5(\sqrt{5}y)+4y^2+1=0$, $\tan(2\theta)=\dfrac{4}{3}$

imply $2\theta=53.1301^\circ$ and the angle of rotation is $\theta=26.56505^\circ$